# How to save a same rdd to multiple cassandra table?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I'm trying to do this mainly because I have to save data from a same stream to two cassandra tables, they have almost same schema but different primary key to serve two queries.

Will

```
rdd.saveToCassandra(keySpace, tableOne, allColumn)
rdd.saveToCassandra(keySpace, tableTwo, allColumn)
```

do the work?

Is this a normal thing to do? I googled a bit and someone said it may incur performance issue when the rdd is large:

https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/spark-connector-user/e1nfWWyhZRo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is OK to do so. To avoid performance issues you need to `cache` your RDD before first use like this:

```
rdd.cache()
```

Also after use it's good practice to `unpersist` your RDD like this:

```
rdd.unpersist()
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I'll do it so and see how it goes.

Comment: Is caching necessary if the RDD is small?

Comment: Caching is not necessary, though the main question is not only how big RDD is, but also how complex the calculations are before writing.